# Tkinter open file window, file extension case sensitivity

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm playing a bit with tkinter for one of my scripts and I have trouble using the `filetypes` argument for the `askopenfilename()` method.

```
INFILE = askopenfilename(filetypes = (("TEST files", "*.test"), ("all files", "*.*")))
```

This is working pretty good but the filter is case sensitive, is there any way to make it not ?
I'd like to be able to see all files with `.test` extension, no matter what the case is (aka: `.teSt .TEST .test`)

I'm pretty sure I don't have to hard write every single combination, so if you have any idea of how to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no  built-in option to do that, but you can for example save the case sensitive extensions in a list and then refer to it:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *


text_file_extensions = ['*.txt', '*.txT', '*.tXT',  '*.Txt', '*.TXt', '*.TXT', '*.tXt',
                        '*.TxT']
ftypes = [
    ('test files', text_file_extensions),
    ('All files', '*'),
]

root = Tk()
root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file",
                                           filetypes=ftypes)
print(root.filename)
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Oh, it's a bit sad there is no built-in solution, I'll go with yours thanks :)
(fortunately my extensions are only two letters long)

Comment: It's worth noting that on case-insensitive (yet case-preserving) filesystems, like Windows, it is not necessary to list all the possible variations of letter-case — having only `text_file_extensions = ['*.txt']` will list files with any variation the case of the three letters to be picked.

Comment: You can algorithmically generate all letter case variations via `chars = ((char.lower(), char.upper()) for char in 'abc')`, then `ftypes = ['*.'+''.join(letters) for letters in itertools.product(*chars)]`.

Comment: Good point, thank you @martineau